# sham + adjective / noun

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I've come across **he shams sick**

Can I say **he shams an idiot** or **he shams pain in his back** ? Do I have to use a person or a thing after sham?

I know it's a rare word but nevertheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to substitute the verb *feigns* for any transitive use of *shams*.

So *He shams idiocy.* rather than *He shams an idiot.*

IMO, *He shams sick* would be better as *He shams illness* because *sick* is not an appropriate object.

Comment: I don't know whether it works that way. Do you have any evidence supporting your answer? This [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shamming+sick%2Fshamming+sickness%2C+feigning+sick%2Ffeigning+sickness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) shows that "shamming sick" is used around as often as "shamming sickness", while "feigning sick" is quite rare compared with "feigning sickness". You can also check that "shamming stupid" is used, but "feigning stupid" is rare compared with "feigning stupidity".